# Disable keyboard and enable just one key in tablet mode

Tags: lenovo

I am writing a script for a Lenovo yoga pro 3 to enable screen rotation and translation, rotation is done via one of the side buttons. When I'm in tablet mode I disable the keyboard and it also disables the buttons on the side of the device. Is there a way to disable all keys except a single key?